# I have a component which contains a custom event that gets fired on button click handled by parent comp

Tags: lightning-aura-components

## MysecondComponent:(child component)

### Markup

---

```
<aura:component controller="CarAppServerClass" extends="c:BaseComponent" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >

   <!--  <aura:attribute name="searchLabel" type="String" default="Search"/>-->
     <aura:attribute type="boolean" name="edit" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="cartypes" type="Car_Type_Name__c[]" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doinit}" />
    <aura:registerEvent name="searchFormSubmit" type="c:CarTypeChange"/>


 <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="center">

<lightning:layoutItem Padding="around-medium">

        <lightning:select name="select item" aura:id='cartypeList' label="all types" variant="label-hidden" value="" >
            <option value="" text="All Types"/>
             <aura:iteration items="{!v.cartypes}" var="cartype">
            <option value="{!cartype.Id}" text="{!cartype.Name}"/></aura:iteration>
        </lightning:select>

 </lightning:layoutItem>

 <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-medium">

      <lightning:button label="Search" variant="brand" onclick="{!c.onsearchclick}"/>
           <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Toggle" onclick="{!c.togglebutton}"/>
           <aura:if isTrue="{!v.edit}">
            <lightning:button label="Create New Type" variant="neutral" onclick="{!c.createcarRecord}"/>
        </aura:if>

    </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
</aura:component>
```

### controller:

---

```
({
onsearchclick : function(component, event, helper) {


    var searchFormSubmit=component.getEvent("searchFormSubmit");

    searchFormSubmit.setParams({

        "carTypeId" : component.find("cartypeList").get("v.value")


    });


    searchFormSubmit.fire();


    },
    togglebutton : function(component, event, helper){
          var currentvalue = component.get("v.edit");
        if(currentvalue){
            component.set("v.edit",false);
        }else{
            component.set("v.edit",true);
        }
    },

    doinit : function(component, event, helper){


       helper.dynamiccartypes(component,event,helper);
    },
  createcarRecord : function (component, event, helper) {
    var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
    createRecordEvent.setParams({
        "entityApiName": "Car_Type_Name__c"
    });
    createRecordEvent.fire();
}

})
```

## CarSearchComponent:(parent)

### Markup:

---

```
<aura:component
extensible="true"implements="//" access="global" >
     <aura:registerEvent name="searchFormSubmit" type="c:CarTypeChange"/>
    <aura:handler name="searchFormSubmitComponent" event="c:CarTypeChange" action="{!c.doFormSubmit}" />
    <lightning:card title="Search Your Car" Class="bottom_margin">
        <c:MysecondComponent />
    </lightning:card>   
</aura:component>
```

### controller:

---

```
({
    doFormSubmit : function(component, event, helper) 

    {

        var carTypeId= event.getParam('carTypeId');
        alert('Selected Car Id :'+carTypeId);
    }
})
```

## Scenario

if i select the car type and click on search button an custom event should be fired and it should be handled by displaying the id of that car selected and that id is passed in parameter of custom event . And that search button is not working.

[image: Lightning component ui looks like this]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Handling Component Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_component_handling_intro.htm):

> The name attribute in `<aura:handler>` must match the name attribute in the `<aura:registerEvent>` tag in the component that fires the event.

Your child component declares an event called `searchFormSubmit`

```
<aura:registerEvent name="searchFormSubmit" type="c:CarTypeChange"/>
```

But your parent component *declares* that event, and registers for a different name:

```
<aura:registerEvent name="searchFormSubmit" type="c:CarTypeChange"/>
<aura:handler name="searchFormSubmitComponent" event="c:CarTypeChange" action="{!c.doFormSubmit}" />
```

You need to change the `name` attribute on the parent event handler to match the child, and remove the extraneous `<aura:registerEvent>` from the parent component.

Comment: Thanks David!! its working now